# Should I use categories or tags in a site were users can follow other users?

Tags: categorization, tagging, taxonomy

I'm creating a website were users can post tutorials. They can follow other people, so they can get their feed.

Right now there are two fields: `title` and `content`.

I'm not very sure whether to add a `tag` or a `category` field. And I wonder if users then will act as some sort of sub-category; different users will write something more specific than a category, (e.g. I may find in the Programming category someone who writes Rails tutorials, and decide to follow him).

I think this is how Twitter works? (I'm not very sure).

Some pro and cons that I can think of:

**Categories:**

Pros:

- It forces users to select a organized set of categories.
- Having categories and subcategories is cleaner than having a bunch of tags (at least in my opinion).

Cons:

- I have to create them myself (I would like the site to be as community-driven as possible).

**Tags:**

Pros:

- Any user can create a tag.
- They are not restricted to a set of categories.

Cons:

- I can't sub-categorize them (less organized)
- There may be duplicate tags

What is the best way to go in this case?

Comment: You might find some useful arguments in these questions, if you haven't already read them: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5920/categories-or-tags-based-navigation?rq=1 and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/does-the-average-user-understand-the-difference-between-tagging-and-categorie.

Comment: @Matt Obee Thanks, I did. I updated my answer to address something a little bit different.

Comment: It's an interesting one. I'm not too sure why the fact that members can follow each other makes a difference to the tag versus category argument. What do you mean by "...if users then will act as some sort of sub-category"?

Comment: @Matt Obee Well, each user will write something more specific than a category, in that case they act as a sort of `sub-category` (not very sure if my right, though).

Comment: @Matt Obee I added an example in my question.

Comment: Is the site only for tutorials for a specific area/topic, or can *all* tutorials be posted?

Comment: @unor There will be many topics. The user can post any kind of tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about using both?

Using predefined categories for the main structure and user defined tags for the subcategories?

Comment: But then how it is decided which tags go to which category?

Comment: didn't know who you targeting...

An example would be stackexchange, the main categories will be tex, ux, physics and so on and the tags are choosen in every category

Comment: Well, they are different sites. Mine is only one.

Comment: thats a point of view... all use the same backend, you got notified for all...

which type of tutorials should be posted there?

e.g. Programming, you could categorize the programming language and use tags for different modules/frameworks or something

Comment: OK, I'll consider that.